# What is axis in Python with Numpy module?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

when I use np.stack, sometimes have to use axis, like axis=1. I don't understand what the axis means for it. for exmaple,

```
c1 = np.ones((2, 3))
c2 = np.zeros((2, 3))
c = np.stack([c1, c2], axis = 1)
```

this shows like,

```
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

what rules make the result?

Comment: in your ide ... type... help(np.stack) .... to obtain help on any numpy related function ... also dir(np)  for a list of available functions...

Answer (score 0):

Axis means the dimension . For a simple example consider [numpy.sum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3],[2,3,1])
sum1=np.sum(a,axis=0)
sum2=np.sum(a,axis=1)
print sum1,sum2
```

This will give me sum1=12 and sum2=[3,5,4]

My array has two dimensions/axis. The first one is of length 2 and the second one is of length 3. So by specifying axis you simpy tell your code along which dimension you want to do your job.

[numpy.ndarray.ndim](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html) can tell you how many axes do you have

Answer (score 0):

actually sum1 gives (3, 5, 4) and sum2 gives (6, 6)
but your comment helped me understand how axis works in Numpy. Thanks.
as I understand, axis = 0 means that it would add along columns, axis = 1 means that it would add along rows.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the arrays are 2d, and `axis` normally refers to one of those 2 dimensions.

```
In [441]: c1
Out[441]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
In [442]: c1.sum(axis=0)
Out[442]: array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])
In [443]: c1.sum(axis=1)
Out[443]: array([ 3.,  3.])
```

Exactly what a function does with the `axis` parameter is up to the function itself.  In the `sum` case is adds 'along' that axis, and returns a value that is 'missing' that axis.  It's easier to see that action than it is to describe it.

The role of `axis` in `concatenate` is illustrated by:

```
In [452]: np.concatenate((c1,c2),axis=0).shape
Out[452]: (4, 3)
In [453]: np.concatenate((c1,c2),axis=1).shape
Out[453]: (2, 6)
```

`stack` adds a dimension.  It's a relatively new API to `concatenate`, and works by first adding a dimension to each input array

```
In [448]: np.stack((c1,c2,c1,c2),axis=0).shape
Out[448]: (4, 2, 3)
In [449]: np.stack((c1,c2,c1,c2),axis=1).shape
Out[449]: (2, 4, 3)
In [450]: np.stack((c1,c2,c1,c2),axis=2).shape
Out[450]: (2, 3, 4)
```